# How to access variables of a class from another file in JAVA

Tags: java, class, object

I am new to java and I am trying to work a simple program. I have created a class and defined the variables like this

```
public class Animal {

    private String age;
    private String color;
    Breed breed;

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Breed getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(Breed breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}

class Breed {
    private String afador;
    private String afaird;
    private String aussiepom;

    public String getAfador() {
        return afador;
    }

    public void setAfador(String afador) {
        this.afador = afador;
    }

    public String getAfaird() {
        return afaird;
    }

    public void setAfaird(String afaird) {
        this.afaird = afaird;
    }

    public String getAussiepom() {
        return aussiepom;
    }

    public void setAussiepom(String aussiepom) {
        this.aussiepom = aussiepom;
    }
}
```

I want to access the variables in class "BREED" from ANOTHER file, with "animal.breed..." which does not work. How can I access the variables in the "BREED" class?? I am not sure if it is because I have the getter and setters in this file, kindly advise on the same.

Comment: that's why you have a getter method.  "does not work" is not helpful, post a [mcve] including errors.

Comment: Java is case sensitive, so `Breed` is not BREED and there is no such this as JAVA. Where do you try to access the data from Breed? Show the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: I typed Breed in uppercase just to emphasize on on the class I was talking about.  I tried to access the data in the Breed class by creating an object of the Animal class like this Animal animal; then tried to use the animal object to access the Breed class variables. I can only get getBreed(); method but not the getAfaird() method that I need.

Comment: `Animal animal` does not create an object. It only declares a variable. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73153660/edit) your question and add the code where you are trying to access `getAfaird()` in the context you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you are trying to do, however, you did not provide any sample code so I will be answering based on assumptions.

To start, you are trying to access a variable from inside of the Breed class through the getter methods. Lets look at some code.

```
// I'm assuming this is similar to what you have set up.

// Make a new breed
Breed breed = new Breed();

// Setting the breed to Afador through your methods
breed.setAfador("Afador");


// Make a new animal
Animal animal = new Animal();

// Set our animal's breed to our newly made breed
animal.setBreed(breed);
```

You mentioned you got the getBreed() method to work, so you must have done something along the lines of

```
animal.getBreed();
```

You then mentioned you could not get getAfaird() method to work, so I assume you did something like this

```
animal.getAfaird();
```

This does not work since getAfaird() does not exist within the Animal class but rather the Breed class. You can only use this getAfaird() method on Breed objects. So you would want to do something like this

```
animal.getBreed().getAfaird();
```

Comment: I want to do animal.getBreed().getAfaird(); but it does not work, I even tried to make the Breed class public but it still does not work.

Comment: if you are simply trying to do animal.getBreed().getAfaird(); it will not work as getAfaird() returns a String and is not void. You have to be using animal.getBreed().getAfaird() in a way that "retrieves" it. For example, doing something along the lines of String animalBreed = animal.getBreed().getAfaird(); will work. Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: It would help if you provided the lines of code that aren't working as I'm only assuming what you are trying to do and getting the context of your problem would make it faster.

Comment: Animal animal; animal.getBreed().  --- This is the line that is giving the error. Trying to use the dot operator after getBreed() does not allow me to access the variables of the Breed class, which I want. I want to access these variables, because I am planning to fetch data from an API later on.

Comment: From the code you provided, it looks like animal is not being initialized, you are only declaring a null variable. Doing animal.getBreed().(any Breed method) will not work as animal is not initialized and was not given a breed. Doing Animal animal = new Animal(); would be creating the actual animal object. With the class code you provided in the question, you would have to create a Breed class aswell and set animal's breed to be that new breed object. This should allow you to use animal.getBreed().(any Breed method).

Comment: I already have the Breed class. Or what did you mean by "create a Breed class as well and set animal's breed to be that new breed object. " kindly clarify

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say "create a Breed object" instead of "create a Breed class". You create the new breed object with the line Breed breed = new Breed(); You then would have to set up this breed object, using your set methods I am going to do for example breed.setAfador("Afador"); to set the breed object. You would then have to set the animal's breed to this new breed by doing animal.setBreed(breed); You can see this more in depth in my original answer code snippet.

Comment: I cannot access the Breed class in the new file, and even setting its access modifier to public gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You must be user the get method:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Breed breed = animal.getBreed();
```

Another option is declare public the breed attribute, but not is a good practique

Comment: I could not make the Breed class public, and the animal.getBreed().getAfaird(); gives an error.